# How can I bulk save ActiveRecord Objects with validation in a fast way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to save 1000 ActiveRecord Models in a fast way. 
I know about several options e.b. batch import gem or native insert with sql. But the problem is that these solutions do not check whether a record already exists.
Before a record gets saved I definitely  need to check before whether this record already exists by checking some attributes. Currently I iterate and do save like this

```
rate = Rate.find_or_create_by(
            :supplier_id => acc.supplier_id,
            :candidate_id => acc.id,
            :total => self.total,
            :catering => self.catering,
            :arrival => arrival,
            :departure => departure

        ) do |r|
          r.arrival = arrival
          r.departure = departure
          r.supplier_id = acc.supplier_id
          r.total = self.total
          r.currency = currency
        end
```

How is this possible in a fast way with a lot of objects?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_or_create`, while a single method, actually performs two DB queries.  Not only is this slow, it's not even a guarantee of uniqueness (just a very high likelihood).  The same is true of `validates :uniqueness`.

The fastest way to do what you want (with a guarantee of uniqueness) would probably be to build a `UNIQUE` constraint or index in the database.  Then, on save, if the insert fails, Rails will raise an exception.  That will prevent duplicate records, as well as being as fast as standard rails.

If you want speed improvements over the "Rails way" (looping through records, as you're already doing), you'll need to get a bit tricky.  From [this article](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/), the fastest way to do it is to build a single insert with all your records in raw SQL, then run that statement.  Of course, that's predicated on guaranteeing within rails that you're not creating any duplicate records.

Comment: Raw sql insert is also what came into my mind for performance reasons. But  I don't want to exit on unique constraint. Is it possible that postgres just skips the record in case it already exists and continues inserting all other valid entries?

Comment: Perhaps, but that's a postgres question, not a rails one.

Comment: That is to say, the answer to your question seems to be "no"